# HTML table showing all data in one row instead of multiple rows with MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using the aws .net sdk to get all security groups and show them in a table like so.

```
public object GetGroups()
    {
        var allSgRequest = new DescribeSecurityGroupsRequest();
        var allSgResponse = client.DescribeSecurityGroups(allSgRequest);
        var allSgGroups = allSgResponse.SecurityGroups;
        return allSgGroups;
    }
```

In my controller I call the method and pass the data into my view like so

```
 public ActionResult SecurityGroups()
    {
        dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
        SecurityGroupModel sgm = new SecurityGroupModel();
        var awsGroups = sgm.GetGroups();
        model.group = awsGroups;
        return View(model);
    }
```

The variable awsGroups looks something like this[image: aws variable]

My table set up in my view uses the datatables plugin for JQuery and looks like this

```
@model dynamic

@{
ViewBag.Title = "SecurityGroups";
}
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery- 1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/DataTables/datatables.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/DataTables/datatables.js"></script>

<h2>SecurityGroups</h2>

<table id="table" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Group ID</th>
        <th>Group Name</th>
        <th>VPC ID</th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     @foreach (var group in Model.group)
     {
     <td>@group.GroupId</td>
     <td>@group.GroupName</td>
     <td>@group.VpcId</td>
     }
 </tbody>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#table').DataTable();
</script>
```

However when I run the program and go into my view the data displays weirdly and shows all of my groups on one row instead of displaying correctly on multiple rows. Something like this [image]

Why is my data being displayed only on one row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `<tr>` tag:

```
 <tbody>
     @foreach (var group in Model.group)
     {
     <tr>
     <td>@group.GroupId</td>
     <td>@group.GroupName</td>
     <td>@group.VpcId</td>
     </tr>
     }
 </tbody>
```

This is really just simple, well formed HTML.  Every  row in a `<table>` is denoted by the `<tr>` tag, without it it's really not even a valid HTML table and how it displays probably varies from browser to browser.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to .net glad it was a simple thing I missed.